# JQuery ajax POST with FormData doesn't send any values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data, cropperjs

There seem to be lots of posts about this, but can't find a solution amongst them and I've hit a brick wall. Help, dear Stackers!

I'm writing a bit of code that lets users choose a profile picture, crop it and then save the cropped image on the server. I'm using the Cropper.js library to handle the actual cropping and have established that's working because I can display the crop live with this code:

```
var imageData = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
var profileimage = document.getElementById('myProfilePhoto');
profileimage.src = imageData;
```

Now I want to send the cropped image to the server, and the best method would appear to be create a blob and Ajax that over to a php script to handle it.

```
cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blob);
    formData.append('uuid', '{a unique identifier}');
    $.ajax({
         type:           'POST',
         url:            '{the php script}',
         data:           formData,
         processData:    false,
         contentType:    false,
         success: function (response) {
             console.log('Upload success: '+response);
         },
         error: function () {
             console.log('Upload error');
         }
    });
});
```

And at this stage I'm just getting my php script to var_dump($_REQUEST) so I can see in the console what the script thinks it's getting. However, the response is just sending back the default $_REQUEST objects like PHPSESSID and no file or uuid input.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Where are you defining `blob`? Is `uuid` being retrieved correctly in your PHP code?

Comment: `blob` is the callback argument. Isn't there any error in the console on the javascript side before sending the request ? If a canvas get tainted by non CORS drawings, the `toDataURL` or `toBlob` functions are throwing errors. See [CORS anabled image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) for more information

Comment: If value is a Blob object and not a File object, then set value to a new File object, representing the same bytes, whose name attribute value is "blob".

Comment: Apologies, I missed the fact you were running the second snippet in the callback.

Comment: So when you do `console.log(blob)` you see the blob? When you look at the network request do you see it?

Comment: What browser are you testing? Make sure your browser supports `FormData APi`

Comment: Rory - uuid isn't coming through either, so this may not be a blob related issue.

Comment: epascarello - yes, if I console.log(blob), I see it in the console: Blob {size: 206760, type: "image/png"}

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending via post in order to see the request put this code

```
 var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob);
formData.append('uuid', '{a unique identifier}');
formData.append('_method', 'PATCH'); <---add this and you're good to go
```

Comment: I excitedly tried this, thinking there's a nice simple solution, but sadly still not getting either the file or the text field at the php end.

Comment: @PeteSE4, did you put this in your html form -->enctype="multipart/form-data

Comment: also open firebug or developer console in chrome navigate to network tab

Comment: jeez - I don't have a HTML form. This is creating the form variables via ajax and posting directly; no HTML form involved. Also, as I understand it, when using FormData() the contentType needs to be false (I did try that as multipart.form-data too, but with no success).

Comment: Ok - curious update. I tried doing some very vanilla tests to make sure ajax itself was working. If I try $.ajax({ type: "POST", url, data{test:"TEST"} }); then no input at the PHP end. Change that to $.ajax({ type: "GET", url, data{test:"TEST"} }); and the PHP sees the 'test' field. So my conclusion is that the blob and FormData are all red herrings and there's simply something up with POSTing via Ajax. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you are submitting correctly to the url ?

Comment: All I'm getting the PHP to do is var_dump($_REQUEST) so I can see what the script is being sent. POST only shows me session variables, GET shows me that test field. Something is very strange...

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was annoyingly simple but frustratingly hard to find.

My server had an .htaccess rewrite rule which automatically changed www. addresses to the non-www version, and obviously I'd been dumb enough to include the www. in the URL I was calling, and it seems that's enough to strip off the $_POST data in these circumstances.

So FormData() and blobs are all red herrings here - it's just a redirect that's the cause.